# How to append a query string to url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to append a query string to all my urls based on user agent

eg: xyz.com/buy.html`to`xyz.com/buy.html?eq=mobile`

`xyz.com/more/buy.html` to `xyz.com/more/buy.html?eq=mobile`

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
```

is detecting the mobile browsers but not able to write proper `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the query string isn't already there:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^eq=mobile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?eq=mobile [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i tried this , but it is not working. URL remains the same for mobile and desktop